# Ender 3 v2 Neo filament retracting

Tags: filament

When printing temp is at 200 °C and the print bed at 50 °C. When the print gets about a height of 4.0 or so, the print head will move to the far left corner on the rear. The filament will retract about 6 inches or so and start beeping. I have to run the filament back in and press print again and usually completes print. It doesn't matter what filament I have loaded, and there is no binding of filament.
New at this so all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your G-code file?

Comment: This sounds as if you have configured the slicer to change filament at a specific height. We need a link to the sliced G-code to be sure.

Comment: You are 100% correct it was setup to do a filament change. I did not realize it kept the settings for next projects.  Thank you very much